# MIPS: Printing Out a Histogram

Tags: mips

I'm writing a MIPS program (assembly language) that takes in 10 integers and prints out a histogram represented by asterisks.

E.g.:

User input of 1, 2, 3, 4

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
```

I have most of this code written already in MIPS. The problem I am running into is printing out the correct length of asterisks. As of now it is simply printing out the a histogram all of the same length; the FIRST user inputed integer.

```
# program functionality:
```

.data

```
menu:   .asciiz     "\n1. New Histogram\n2. Print Histogram\n3. Quit\n"
prompt: .asciiz     "\nEnter 10 numbers between 0 and 50 (inclusive):\n"
prompt1: .asciiz    "\nEnter a valid number:\n"
asterisk: .asciiz   "*"
space: .asciiz      "\n"
array:  .word       0:10
```

.text
    main:

```
do:

    jal print_menu
    li  $v0, 5
    syscall

    beq $v0, 1, new
    beq $v0, 2, print
    beq $v0, 3, quit
j   do  # end do

    new:
        jal new_user
        j   do
    print:
        jal print_user
        j   do

j   quit

print_menu:

    la  $a0, menu
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    jr  $ra


new_user:
    la  $a0, prompt
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall


    enter_loop:

        la  $t0, array
        li  $t1, 10

        enter_loop_2:

            la  $a0, prompt1
            li  $v0, 4
            syscall

            li  $v0, 5
            syscall

            sw  $v0, ($t0)

            addi    $t1, $t1, -1
            beqz    $t1, end_loop_2

            addi    $t0, $t0, 4
            j   enter_loop_2


            end_loop_2:
            jr  $ra


print_user:
    la  $t0, array
    li  $t1, 10

    pLoop:

    la  $a0, space
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall


        asterisk_fun:


            li  $v0, 1
            lw  $a0, ($t0)
            syscall


            counter:

                la  $a0, asterisk
                li  $v0, 4
                syscall

                addi    $a0, $a0, -1
                beqz    $a0, asterisk_end

                j   counter

            asterisk_end:

                jr  $ra



        addi    $t1, $t1, -1
        beqz    $t1, endpLoop

        addi    $t0, $t0, 4

        j   pLoop


        endpLoop:
        jr  $ra



quit:
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that you are overwriting register `$a0` in counter with the address of the asterisk, and you also used `$a0` to count the number of items in that bucket.
Easy solution is to use other register (e.g. `$a1`) to count the number of items:

That would be:

```
     #... your code
    asterisk_fun:
        li  $v0, 1
        lw  $a1, ($t0)   # Load number in $a1
        move $a0, $a1    # move to $a0 just to print it
        syscall
            la  $a0, asterisk
        counter:

            li  $v0, 4
            syscall

            addi    $a1, $a1, -1          # we use $a1 to keep the counter
            beqz    $a1, asterisk_end

            j   counter

        asterisk_end:
     # ... more of your code
```